# Misunderstanding of Atiyah-Singer

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, spectral-theory

I just looked up the Atiyah-Singer theorem and by ignoring technical details I had the impression that it tells us that any elliptic operator on a compact manifold satisfies

Analytical index = Topological index.

Now, if I pick the Laplacian on such a manifold, then this is an elliptic operator. But clearly the analytical index of the Laplacian is always zero( operator is self-adjoint.)

So I just proved Topological index=0 for any compact manifold, which is clearly nonsense. What did I do wrong?

Comment: "I just proved Topological index=0 for any compact manifold..."  IIRC, the index is a property of the operator, not the manifold.

Comment: how do you define the topological index of an operator?

Comment: Topology is where I currently get off the train, but [this might help](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atiyah%E2%80%93Singer_index_theorem#Topological_index).  It appears that the topological index depends on both the manifold and the operator (which intuitively makes sense in the context of the A-S theorem).

Comment: The topological index, whose definition is quite involved, depends on the [symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbol_of_a_differential_operator#Vector_bundles) of the differential operator.

Comment: You can start by reading https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atiyah%E2%80%93Singer_index_theorem

Comment: It is actually fairly straightforward to see that the Laplacian has zero topological index by hand, since its symbol on the unit sphere is $-I$. It is obvious that you can extend this isomorphism $\Lambda^k T^*M \to \Lambda^k T^*M$ to the whole unit disc bundle, just by defining it to be $-I$ everywhere. So the symbol gives the zero element in relative K-theory, and hence has index zero.